# Solving Quadratic program for finding perfect matching in polynomial time

Tags: graph-theory, convex-optimization, linear-programming, positive-semidefinite, matching-theory

I am working on a variant of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). The original assignment problem is as follows:
We are given a bipartite graph with 2n vertices. Each edge has a non-negative integer weight $w_{i,j}$. Missing edges can be handled by giving them very high edge weights. The problem is to find the minimum weight perfect matching. This can be expressed as a linear program:

$\min \sum_{i,j} w_{i,j}x_{i,j}$

such that

$\sum_{i}x_{i,j}=1$

$\sum_{j}x_{i,j}=1$
$x_{ij}\ge0$

This problem can be solved in polynomial time using general purpose linear programming approaches, or even specialized algorithms such as the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

However, I am interested in finding a perfect matching with a particular weight say W (not minimal). Naively, if we add the constraint $\sum_{i,j}w_{i,j}x_{i,j}\ge W$ to the above linear program, then I don't think we can get integer 0/1 solutions to $x_{i,j}$s since the constraints are no longer totally-unimodular (please correct me if I'm wrong on this).

Another approach I thought of was to encode it as a quadratic program with linear constraints:

$\min \left(\sum_{i,j} w_{i,j}x_{i,j} - W\right)^2$

such that

$\sum_{i}x_{i,j}=1$

$\sum_{j}x_{i,j}=1$
$x_{ij}\ge0$

If $\vec{w}$ is the vector of edge weights, then the squared term can be expressed as
$\vec{x}^{T}\textbf{Q}\vec{x}$, where the matrix $\textbf{Q} = \vec{w}\vec{w}^{T}$, which I believe is positive semidefinite.

My question is, can this quadratic program be solved in polynomial time? Will the optimal $x_{i,j}$s be 0/1 since constraints are totally-unimodular? I am not very familiar with optimization theory so any help will be appreciated.

More generally, is there a way of finding a perfect matching with a particular weight W in polynomial time? Thanks!

Comment: What is the application for this?  Why would you ever want to do worse than the optimum?

Comment: @saulspatz I eventually want to enumerate assignments of a particular weight one-by-one. First step is towards that is finding one assignment efficiently.

Comment: Do you realize that even counting the number of maximal matchings in an **unweighted** bipartite graph is #P-complete?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes I know. I don't want to enumerate all - just a few. [Murty's algorithm](https://www.jstor.org/stable/168595?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) can be used to enumerate the k-best assignments in ascending order of their weight. However, I cannot use that here, as there maybe exponentially many assignments with weights smaller than W.

Comment: What makes you think that the solution to this QP will be 0-1?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I am not very familiar with optimization theory so correct me if I'm wrong, but I was thinking (hoping) that since the set of constraints to the QP are totally-unimodular, it would result in 0-1 solutions like it does for the LP.

Comment: Consider what happens when you minimize $(x-1/2)^2$ subject to the constraints $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers but in this case W is an integer greater than 1 and also there is the non-negative integral weight vector $\vec{w}$. It's not very clear to me how that would preclude 0-1 solutions

Comment: Take CVX and try. It only takes a few minutes to see that you do not, in general, get optimal 0/1 solutions.